# prestashop module not showing in left and right column?

Tags: php, e-commerce, prestashop

I am a newbie to the prestashop modules development. Currently I have developed a module. It is working fine in backend (like update and delete inserted values). But when I tried to check the function of the module from frontend it is not showing. My code for install the module is look like this

```
 public function install()
  {
    if(!parent::install())
      return false;
    if (!$this->registerHook('leftColumn'))
      return false;
    if (!$this->registerHook('header'))
      return false;
    if (!$this->registerHook('rightColumn'))
      return false;
      return true;
   }
```

The code for the hook is like this

```
 public function hookHome($params)
  {
    global $cookie, $smarty;
    $value=array();
    .....................
    ............
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'filename.tpl');
  }
```

I have tried many methods to show the module in left column and the right column of the page but its not showing there.

But when I tried to transplant the module from `admin->modules->positions->transplant a module->hook into->displayHome (Homepage content)`. it worked in homepage content. But I want to show them in left and right column also. I have tried to use live edit but the module is not showing in left and right column at all. So can someone tell me what is the wrong here? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you register a hook in your module, you have to define a method to call when the hook is fired. In your case, you have to define the following methods :

```
public function hookLeftColumn($params)
{
    // Do your stuff on left column
}

public function hookRightColumn($params)
{
    // Do your stuff on right column
}

public function hookHeader($params)
{
    // Do your stuff in the header
}
```

Comment: His post implies he already knows this, and is asking why its not working.

Answer (score 0):

For each registered hook, you must create a non-static public method, starting with the “hook” keyword followed by the name of the hook you want to use (starting with either “display” or “action”).

```
<?php
public function hookDisplayLeftColumn($params)
{
    // Your code.
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'filename.tpl');
}

public function hookDisplayRightColumn($params)
{
    // Your code.
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'filename.tpl');
}

public function hookActionOtherHook($params)
{
    // Your code.
   }
```

Good Luck!